# SVN copy from one branch to another

Tags: svn

I have a typical problem with SVN. I did a search in this repository but they are not of my kind of problem.

I have the svn setup this way.

```
"     |--- New development branch
trunk ------------ ---------------------Development Branch
    "        |--base tag-----|release tag
```

I'm currently working on `Development Branch` and did lot changes. Admin now created `New development branch` copied everything from `base tag` and now ask me to use `New development branch` for my further development.

My question is how do i get all my files copied to `New development branch` and then start using the new branch in my current working directory [ I still have files no checked-in and working state].

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called *merge*.  It will take your changes and apply the ones that are newer then what's in new-dev (coming from base-tag) to that branch.

*Note*: if there were modifications on base-tag or new-dev since base-tag was copied from trunk, you might get some conflicts (conflicting edits to the same file/folder) that you will have to resolve manually.  Most of the time this should not be a problem as svn will be able to figure out how to merge the changes

Comment: What flavor of svn client are you using (e.g. command-line versionm TortoiseSVN)?

Comment: svn, version 1.4.2 , CLI on Linux platform.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) and [this wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Quick_SVN_merging_guide)